# MongoDB - Very poor mongos performance

Tags: mongodb, nosql

We are testing MongoDB 2.6.1 for a new deployment, and have the following lab:

Replica Set 0: Primary + Secondary + Arbiter
Replica Set 1: Primary + Secondary + Arbiter
One config server
One dedicated mongos server (for sharding)

We are seeing a LOT of difference between a mongoimport directly to one RS (about 15000 inserts/sec) and passing through mongos router (1800 inserts/sec), including with no sharding at all (new fresh database and collection).
There is no network or CPU congestion on mongos machine.
No matters what replica set we use to load data, both performs about 15000 inserts per second if mongoimport runs directly against mongod.

Which could be the problem?
Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "including with no sharding at all" could be your problem. If you haven't run `sh.addShard('rs0/address:port'); sh.enableSharding('db');` you are likely inserting data to the mongos instance instead of the mongod. When you do these experiments, try accessing the `replica set 0` mongod directly and seeing if the data is getting in there.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Note that stackoverflow is a community for programmers facing programming challenges. Your question, however, is about administration of databases and thus off-topic here. However, we have a sister-site http://dba.stackexchange.com where your question would fit much better.

Comment: Thanks both for your help. Finally we find that the problem is (strangely) only on one database, no matters if we insert on a new collection.